# Android app ActionBarSherlock integration error

Tags: android, dependencies, actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio

I have been following [this](http://armanpagilagan.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/using-actionbarsherlock-in-android.html) tutorial for integrating ActionBarSherlock in the Android Studio IDE.

After following all the steps I get the following error:

```
Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':MyApp'.
> Could not find property ':actionbarsherlock' on DefaultProjectDependency{dependencyProject='project ':MyApp'', configuration='default'}.
```

The source of the error is my AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\myapp\build.gradle file with the contents as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile project ':actionbarsherlock'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a late answer, but try like that :

```
compile project(':actionbarsherlock')
```